# Angular Grid resizing and a transition effect

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, transition, angular-grid

I have a page with an Angular Grid and I have it set up so that I am able to click a button and resize the grid's pane from the default 70% to 100%. I do have to rely on calling the grid api method "handleWindowResize" method so that the grid columns get properly resized/reformatted after the stretch happens.

However, I would like to throw in a css transition `transition:width 2s` so that's it's not such blip on the screen. However the `handleWindowResize` runs before the transition is able to complete so I end up with an incomplete grid. I also would not be able to call the `handleWindowResize` after the css transition completes because then the transition only happens to the header part of the grid and then the resize blips again and it all looks ugly.

What I need is for the `handleWindowResize` to be called throughout the transition's process as so it looks like the grid is stretching along with the transition but I am unable to come up with the Javascript to accomplish this.  Effectively the the transition and the `handleWindowResize` needs to be running in sync and then the `handleWindowResize` would be run once more on completion so it looks like a fluid screen stretch.

http://ui-grid.info/

Currently the code is:

```
document.querySelector(".some-btn").on("click", function(){
    document.querySelect(".the-grid").setAttribute("style", "width: 100%; transition: 2s");
    $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize(); // need this to run many times as the grid is transitioning in size.
})
```

Comment: What grid plugin are you using by chance?  It sounds like you're using UI-Grid http://ui-grid.info/  Is that the right one?

Comment: It is http://ui-grid.info/

Thanks, added to main post.